# Oracle SQL COUNT function to count 1 or more and not return the actual count

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, query-optimization

So we have a situation where the query looks something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(account_number) FROM ACCOUNTS
```

Depending upon the count, we display either a single account number on the UI, or a link to drill down deeper (there is another DECODE in the query where we check COUNT value and select single account number if it is 1). So in a way, we are only interested in knowing whether the count is 1 or more, and not interested in the actual count.

The issue is that we have multiple instances of such counts and multiple joins and it is causing a huge performance issue.

Is there a way to avoid the full counting and simply know whether it is 1 or more?

Comment: `select count(account_number) from ( select * from accounts where account_number is not null and rownum < 3)`

Comment: You mention multiple joins, but that isn't shown in the SQL you posted. If you have a performance issue and it isn't resolved by implementing @astentx's suggestion, you'll need to share the entire SQL.

Answer (score 4):

The following query will be much faster

`SELECT COUNT(account_number) FROM ACCOUNTS WHERE rownum=1`

It will return 1 if there is at least one row in the table and 0 otherwise.